# How to use an oEmbed json response in my React App

Tags: reactjs, oembed

I'm trying to embed an oEmbed response in my React app. The Response looks like this.

```html
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "video",
  "title": "Scramble up ur name & I’ll try to guess it❤️ #foryoupage #petsoftiktok #aesthetic",
  "author_url": "https://www.tiktok.com/@scout2015",
  "author_name": "Scout & Suki",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "html": "<blockquote class=\"tiktok-embed\" cite=\"https://www.tiktok.com/@scout2015/video/6718335390845095173\" data-video-id=\"6718335390845095173\" style=\"max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;\" > <section> <a target=\"_blank\" title=\"@scout2015\" href=\"https://www.tiktok.com/@scout2015\">@scout2015</a> <p>Scramble up ur name & I’ll try to guess it❤️ <a title=\"foryoupage\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.tiktok.com/tag/foryoupage\">#foryoupage</a> <a title=\"petsoftiktok\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.tiktok.com/tag/petsoftiktok\">#petsoftiktok</a> <a title=\"aesthetic\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.tiktok.com/tag/aesthetic\">#aesthetic</a></p> <a target=\"_blank\" title=\"♬ original sound - \" href=\"https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-6689804660171082501\">♬ original sound - </a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src=\"https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js\"></script>",
  "thumbnail_width": 720,
  "thumbnail_height": 1280,
  "thumbnail_url": "https://p16.muscdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/06kv6rfcesljdjr45ukb0000d844090v0200010605",
  "provider_url": "https://www.tiktok.com",
  "provider_name": "TikTok"
}
```

I would like to simply render this in my react app. Using the html doesn't work. I don't want to have to change anything within the response, as the user will provide a link so there will be many different responses, I'm not just doing this once.

So what is the correct way to use this response in my React app? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear in what manner do you wish to embed the response.

if you mean display the JSON on the page:

```js
<div><pre>{JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}</pre></div>
```

if you meant rendering the enclosed HTML you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```js
function createMarkup(html) {
  return {__html: html};
}

function MyComponent() {
  // where response = <your response json>
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(response.html)} />;
}
```

read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: Wanted was to have this html carry with it the styles provided in the script tag. I was able to fix this by taking that script tag and putting it in my index.html. I will take that response html and put it in the dangerouslySetInnerHTML, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By taking their script tag and putting it into my index.html and then rendering the given html in dangerouslySetInnerHTML I was able to get the tiktok to embed correctly with the styles.